# Run a certain behavior if click target is only on one element but not another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click, tinymce

I've got a bit of a jQuery intensive user experience.
I'm having an issue in making sure a certain dialog box opens only when the click target is one item but not another.

Basically, I want the "edit text" dialog to show up only when the user clicks on a div with class `.textbox` (which happens to be in `#content` div), but not when the user clicks on a part of the instantiated `tinyMCE` instance (such as its options etc). I've set up tinyMCE so that when activated, the toolbar appears in `#externalToolbarWrapper`.

This is my code:

```
    // check if the click's target element is parented by a textbox or mceLayout.
    var $etextbox = $(e.target).closest('.textbox');
    var $etoolbar = $(e.target).closest('.mceLayout');

if($etextbox.length==1 && $etoolbar.length == 0) // only the text parent and not toolbar is clicked
{
         doStuff();
}
```

However, using this code, `doStuff` is triggered even when the click was made outside the `content` box, and on a part of the TinyMCE toolbar (such as to change a font or size).
So I tried adding a few more possibilities:

```
    var $eformat = $(e.target).closest('#externalToolbarWrapper');
    var $econtent = $(e.target).closest('#content');
```

And then I output in the console:

```
console.log("textbox: " + $etextbox.length);
console.log("etoolbar: " + $etoolbar.length);
console.log("eformat: " + $eformat.length);
console.log("econtent: " + $econtent.length);
```

But after a click on the TinyMCE toolbar, I get the following results:

```
etextbox: 0 
etoolbar: 0 
emenu: 0 
eformat: 0 
econtent: 1
```

and I tried an additional check:

```
if($etextbox.length==1 && $etoolbar.length == 0 && $etoolbar.length==0 && $eformat.length==0)
```

but even when the click takes place outside the `content` div and on the toolbar, it's still counted and so `doStuff()` always triggers. So apparently none of the conditions I tried help to ever detect that the click was made on a TinyMCE toolbar and not on a textbox.

How can I make sure the click only triggers my function when the click is directly on the `textbox` div, and not otherwise?

Comment: This is due to event propagation and buble up..u hv to cancel those..

Comment: I tried `e.stopPropagation();` but then nothing works at all! Where should I add it so that `doStuff()` gets called but not on the TinyMCE toolbar? @Thariama do you have any clue?

Comment: did you check the target on the click event? the first parameter on the click event function holds the `event` object. `console.log` that and see if it is different when you click a tiny-element and the textbox

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved this problem simply by checking the `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` coordinates and making sure they weren't within the `#content` div. So if the click was outside the content, it didn't trigger `doStuff()`.